# Missing GPU output device

Tags: sound, 22.04, gpu, amdgpu, output

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and a RX 580. After a system update the output device that I used on with my TV is missing. It was something like `Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]`.

The "Dispositivos de reprodução" section represents the output devices and now it only has my USB headset as seen in the image below.

[image: audio devices]

I tried installing the amdgpu driver and it's still missing.